# swizzle NSMutableArray addObject: failed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I failed to swizzle NSMutableArray addObject. code as follows:

```
Method ori_Mehtod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(addObject:));
Method swi_Method = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(swi_addObject:));
method_exchangeImplementations(ori_Mehtod, swi_Method);
```

But, I have found a useful way, as follows:

```
Method orig = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"__NSArrayM"), NSSelectorFromString(@"addObject:"));
Method override = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"__NSArrayM"), @selector(addObject_override:));
method_exchangeImplementations(orig, override);
```

I guess there are something wrong in [self class]. But I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: What is the result of ` [self class]` ?

Comment: I guess the next question is: what are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's another way?

Answer (score 2):

`NSMutableArray` is a class cluster.  Instances are always of a hidden class type (such as the `__NSArrayM` that you found), so swizzling the `NSMutableArray` class itself does little good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a way to swizzle cluster,  have a look at [NSObjectSafe](https://github.com/jasenhuang/NSObjectSafe), it's a tiny open source framework which hook most of commonly used function of Foundation container such as [NSMutableArray addObject:]

Answer (score 0):

[ClassClusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)

[Refer to the SafeKit Library](https://github.com/JJMM/SafeKit)

Comment: Greetings. Please check out [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)